# How to add dependency of type @jar in build.gradle using format of group,name,version,type?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-studio

The pom.xml of dependency is describle with `<packaging>apk</packaging>`,which isn't workable in compile.
So I exclude the module in dependency tree and re-include by
`compile 'package:artifactId:versionName@jar'`
This does work,but what's the corresponding format of `group:'groupName',name:'artifactId',version:'versionName',type:'type'` ?
I tried`type:'jar'` which didn't work.
And do I have to exclude the dependency in dependency tree first , then re-include it second ? Or I can modify the description of parent dependency ?

parent dependency:

```
compile (group:'parentGroupId',name:'parentModuleName',version:'parentVersion'){
    exclude group:'excludeGroupId',module:'excludeModuleName'
}

compile 'excludeGroupId:excludeModuleName:excludeVersion@jar'
```

I tried

```
compile (group:'parentGroupId',name:'parentModuleName',version:'parentVersion'){
    exclude group:'excludeGroupId',module:'excludeModuleName'
}

compile (group:'excludeGroupId',name:'excludeModuleName',version:'excludeVersion',type:'jar')
```

the above didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the docs at http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html this looks like the correct way to specify this sort of dependency:

```
compile (group:'excludeGroupId',name:'excludeModuleName',version:'excludeVersion') {
    artifact {
        name = 'excludeModuleName'
        type = 'jar'
    }
}
```

Note that the redundant `name` spec inside `artifact` is required -- you'll get a `NullPointerException` without it.